# Express not setting HTTPOnly cookie in production

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, session-cookies

I'm using firebase with session cookies to authenticate users on my react website. The backend is using google cloud functions. When i login on my website on localhost everything is working fine; my react app is running on `localhost:3000` and my cloud functions are running on `locahost:5000`. My initialization code looks like this:

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://beta.example.com','https://example.com']}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));

app.use(cookieParser());
```

The login code looks like this:

```
const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();

  // Set session expiration to 5 days.
  const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
  admin
    .auth()
    .createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn })
    .then((sessionCookie) => {
      const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: false };
      res.cookie("session", sessionCookie, options);
      return res.json({ message: "Logged in!" });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return res
        .status(403)
        .json({ general: "Wrong credentials, please try again" });
    });
};
```

The issue seems to be cross domain, since my website is hosted on another domain than google cloud functions are, and I cannot set the cookie no matter what I try. I have tried to uuse axios and fetch doing the requests, and they are both working on localhost. here is the fetch from my frontend:

```
fetch(api_url + "/login", {
        method: "POST",
        redirect: "follow",
        credentials: "include", // Don't forget to specify this if you need cookies
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          idToken: idToken,
        }),
      }).then((res) => {
        console.log("LOGGED IN!!!", res.data);
        dispatch(getuserData(true, history, url));
      });
```

I can see the cookie called "session" when using localhost, it's being created as it should; when I press the login button on my site. This cookies is not present when press the same login button on my custom domain

Quick note, the backend is not crashing, it just doesn't save the cookie on the server for some reason

Answer (score 1):

> Cookies do not provide isolation by port. If a cookie is readable by a service running on one port, the cookie is also readable by a service running on another port of the same server.

That's the reason. When you're working on local, both of your frontend and backend api belong to localhost domain.

On production environment, you're probably deploying frontend and backend api on different endpoints.
For SPA application, I recommend to use localStorage instead of cookies.

Comment: Yes that was also what i said in my post, that the issue is cross domain cookies.

Comment: There is no way to solve it if you deploy frontend and backend on different domains. If you still wanna use cookies, the common way is making a proxy to your backend via a sub route like /api but it should be another topic.

Comment: Also, you could look into subdomains. For example, you have ```example.com``` and ```api.example.com```. If the root domain obtains the cookie, it is then visible in the subdomains.

Comment: You should not use localStorage for login information because it's not secure. You should be using httponly cookies